# How to draw endless 2D board/map if AbsoluteLayout is deprecated?

Tags: android, css-position, world-map

I wish to draw endless board like game world map of endless cell grid. User will be able to scroll it, but the data will be stored in memory, not on scree. I.e. I will populate cells when they are appear on screen and delete them on hide.

How to implement this in Android?

In javascript and java I would use 2 nested absolute panes or divs with no clipping.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing with a RelativeLayout by changing the view's left and top margin as if it was the x and y coordinate.

Comment: Can you point to some samples pls? Or provide some very simplistic code?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to override onDraw(Canvas canvas) method of View sub-class and paint the area you want to display. Put your game character in the center and redraw the View with invalidate().

Comment: I want to move the map smoothly. Will it work good with canvas drawing?

Comment: If you want able user to drag (or scroll) view to right, left, top or down, override onScroll() event listener and based on new X and Y, redraw your canvas (by calling invalidate on View object)

Comment: It depends on your onDraw() method. Take a look at mapping apps. They redraw map on scroll. If you scroll map 100 pixles, they redraw map about 100 times and they are still very fast. I have no experience with games, but if you are interested, you can look at osmdroid mapping application that is open source: code.google.com/p/osmdroid/